# Status code:403 exit status 1 golang

Tags: golang, web-scraping, http-status-code-403

Первый раз пишу парсер. Нашел видео, но у преподавателя не появляется такая ошибка. Status code:403
exit status 1

Вот кусок кода, который отвечает за это.

```
func getHtml(url string) *http.Response {
    response, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if response.StatusCode > 400 {
        log.Fatal("Status code:", response.StatusCode)
    }
    return response
}
```

Comment: Ну сайт, что вы пытаетесь парсить возвращает 403 ошибку. 403 это доступ запрещен.

Comment: Получается, что я вообще не смогу это сделать? Или нужен другой способ?(Который мне по силам:)

Comment: Смотря что вы там парсите. Предполагаю, что пытаетесь спарсить какой-то кабинет или часть сайта, где нужна авторизация. Нужно больше подробностей.

Comment: Я пробую парсить интернет магазин связной
https://www.svyaznoy.ru/catalog/accessories/198?FILTER%5Bbrand%5D%5B0%5D=218247&FILTER%5Bbrand%5D%5B1%5D=218237&ORDER_BY=-discount

Comment: может быть вы хотите получить доступ к личным данным, но для этого вам нужно злогиниться. а ваш запрос этого не делает, поэтому сайт возвращает "403 доступ запрещен"

Comment: Но там нет авторизации. Хочу просто взять заголовок, цену и ссылку каждого товара.